# How to Match Orders to User Sessions in WPeC

Tags: plugin-wp-e-commerce, flash

This is less a technical question, and more a ’how would you do it’ question that I’m hoping the more experienced users may have some advice on… (I still think its a valid question for this forum)

I’m creating a Flash application which allows users to upload an image, and then add a product to the shopping basket with that image on it (WPeC plugin is my shopping basket - I'm going to need to add a product to my shopping basket from within the flash application).

My problem is this… many users will upload images, but not all will actually complete the order. When a user orders a product, I need to know which image on my server is their image!

I thought about naming each image uploaded with the users Session Id, then when someone orders a customised product I would *somehow* find the session id and match them up.

I ruled this out because a user might upload 3 or 4 images – each image would have the same Session Id so I wouldn’t be able to tell which image they wanted to use.

Knowing what I’m trying to do, do you have any advice on how to go about this? Before I even start to work out the technical side of things I’d like to get a plan together of matching images to orders.

PLEASE HELP IF YOU CAN!

Thank you

Dean

Comment: The getshopped support forum has been broken for days and no response from any staff as to when it'll be fixed or rolled back to the old working forum (hence posting here searching for help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

upload the file and add the item to the cart in one process, passing the filename as extra meta data with the cart item. if they remove the item from the cart, you can delete the file so you don't have abandoned files.

Comment: Thanks Milo, makes perfect sense to me. When they add the item to basket I'll upload to the server (currently I'm uploading to server before they add to basket) and will delete file when they remove from cart (I'll do some searching on how to best do this).